# How to scroll down div automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a main div and it contains number of sub divs. Each sub div contain a sentence and By using setInterval() function I changed the sub div background color.(It just like selecting a sentence for a short time)As main div height is smaller than number of sub divs' height, all sentences can't show at once in main div. So I set scroll property to main div.

Suppose main div height can show only 5 sentences.Then, when we run the code we can see that 5 sentences are changed background color one by one, but we can't see whether the other sentences changed their background color or not without scroll the div.

I need to show changed background color div always. That means div must be automatically scroll and show the changed background color div. Can anyone please tell me how to auto scroll div according to my need?

My code:

```js
var rootNo=1;
document.getElementById(rootNo.toString()).style.backgroundColor = '#00BFFF';

var interval = setInterval(function() {
   document.getElementById(rootNo.toString()).style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF99';
   rootNo++;
   document.getElementById(rootNo.toString()).style.backgroundColor = '#00BFFF'; 
   
   if(rootNo==30){
      clearInterval(interval);
   }
          
}, 1000);
```

```css
.mainDiv{
    width: 50%;
    height: 1%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: '#FFFF99';
}
    
.subDiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: '#FFFF99';
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
    
    <div class="subDiv" id="1">sentence 1</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="2">sentence 2</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="3">sentence 3</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="4">sentence 4</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="5">sentence 5</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="6">sentence 6</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="7">sentence 7</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="8">sentence 8</div>   
    <div class="subDiv" id="9">sentence 9</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="10">sentence 10</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="11">sentence 11</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="12">sentence 12</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="13">sentence 13</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="14">sentence 14</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="15">sentence 15</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="16">sentence 16</div> 
    <div class="subDiv" id="17">sentence 17</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="18">sentence 18</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="19">sentence 19</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="20">sentence 20</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="21">sentence 21</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="22">sentence 22</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="23">sentence 23</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="24">sentence 24</div> 
    <div class="subDiv" id="25">sentence 25</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="26">sentence 26</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="27">sentence 27</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="28">sentence 28</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="29">sentence 29</div>
    <div class="subDiv" id="30">sentence 30</div>   
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you planning to use JQuery?

Comment: @Desi Delite The answer could be given based on where do you want scroll(scroll-bar). Do you want  to have scroll-bar stick with that main div or with the body? Based on that answer could be prepared.

Comment: Yeah, a bit more info on how the element will look like exactly would be required - does it have fixed dimensions (and overflow) or is it responsive somehow? Should each next visibly sentence be scrolled to one by one or whenever the edge is reached, scroll a larger amount to completely show the next cluster...

Comment: @Shikkediel & @ divy3993 ,Actually I need something like this.When  the main div height is smaller than sum of sub div height, we need to scroll the main div to see all other sub divs. When you run this code you can see sub div background color change one by one and it goes down.we can see this color changing in first sub div set. and then we can't see that change without scrolling the main div. I need to know that is there any way to show changing color div without scroll by us. can we focus each changing color div by automatically scrolling. this given answer is not the answer I wished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

https://jsbin.com/qilorebizo

I have modified your js:

```
var rootNo=1;
document.getElementById(rootNo.toString()).style.backgroundColor = '#00BFFF';
var mainDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('mainDiv')[0];

function getSubDivPos(id) {
  var pos = 0;
  var iNode;
  for(var i = 0; i < mainDiv.children.length; i++) {
    iNode = mainDiv.children[i];
    if(iNode.id == id){
      break;
    }
    pos += iNode.clientHeight;
  }
  return pos;
}

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var currentNode = document.getElementById(rootNo.toString());
    currentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF99';
    rootNo++;
    var nextNode = document.getElementById(rootNo.toString());
    nextNode.style.backgroundColor = '#00BFFF'; 

    if(rootNo==30){
       clearInterval(interval);
    }

    mainDiv.scrollTop = getSubDivPos(rootNo);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll-down or top like below:

```js
$(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<div id="top">Some things here</div> .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here .Some things here ..<a href="#top">TOP</a>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mostafas/2h8kgL6o/)
Note: for some reason it's dont work correctly in stackoverflow snippets but in jsfiddle work correctly.